# FBSession.activeSession.permissions does not appear to accurately depict the valid granted permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am observing the following....

I authenticate a user via the following (note that in the completion block I am nslogging the permissions)

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"email", @"publish_actions",
                        nil];

 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                 NSLog(@"permissions %@",FBSession.activeSession.permissions);
 }];
```

As a user I start up the app and proceed to login w/ FB.

1. I am presented with a screen that reads "app would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address." and I select "ok"
2. I am presented with a screen that reads "app would like to post to your friends on your behalf" and I select "skip".

3) The completion block code spits out the permissions as the following

permissions (
    email,
    "publish_actions"
)

Why is publish_actions listed? If I try to post to FB now through the app it will error out and tell me that I don't have the right permissions......yet I cannot check for this case b/c FBSession.activeSession.permissions tells me that I have the "publish_actions" permission even when in reality I do not.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm getting this too I think I need to close down session and open another

Answer (score 0):

If you were using **iOS SDK 3.0**, then this was due to a bug in the SDK. See the [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/111727002307769) for more details.

Symptom summary:

> After authorizing user with openActiveSessionWithPermissions  method, the sessions variable in callback method contains extended permissions that were not allowed by a user.